# Imagesc with holdon property

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How to use the imagesc with holdon property. I would like to plot two images on a same figure by using different colors. However when I tried to use holdon then It plotted tha last image.

any idea about this.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: `hold on` or `holdon`? Please click the "edit" link under your question and add some code to demonstrate what you're trying to do and how - how do you plot an *image*?

Comment: `holdon` does not exist so I guess you mean `hold on`. Anyway your question lacks contents in order to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate function to do this is [`imshowpair`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html), not `imagesc`.

Then, provided that you didn't post neither your images, your code or what result you would like to obtain it's impossible to help more.

Best,